# Как устроен бот Feeds для основного чата сообщества?

Tags: поддержка, чат

В основном чате сообщества есть бот Feeds, который постит уведомления о новых темах на мете, новых ответах в существующие темы -- и мне нравится эта фича so.

К сожалению, не секрет, что этого бота частенько глючит:

- бот может сообщить о новой теме намного позже, чем через пять минут (видимо, пять минут -- это цикл таймера для опроса);
- бот может совсем "забыть" уведомить о новой теме/новом ответе. Из предположения, что бот завис в некоторый момент -- есть заметная вероятность, что на очередном цикле бот пропустит часть уведомлений;
- бот может "выплюнуть" в чат сразу несколько пропущенных уведомлений ("о, проснулся наконец!"), но любопытно, что среди запоздавших уведомлений (допустим, их должно быть три) может не быть того, которое посередине (два пришло, а одно нет: то, которое пришло бы вторым).

В общем-то, мне хочется, чтобы бот работал как часы, без проблем и глюков, а потому вопрос: как он так устроен внутри и что у него там постоянно ломается?

Comment: Вкратце, это просто обновления RSS ленты. Можно настроить разные ленты в каждом чате. В основном сейчас [такие](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kItom.jpg).